# Looping over the rows of a dataframe and use it as function input in r

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, stringr

I want to loop over a table with categories to assign a subcategory to a column in another dataframe called 'data'. The text is handwritten by a person and is a character field which contains around 100 words, but is dynamic in length. I want to check if the word provided in 'search_pat' is in the field 'text' if it is and the 'category' is also matched, the subcat must be assigned.The apply function i do in the code below provides me the result:
`"cat1" "cat2"`

But my desired result is the same dataframe 'data' but then with filled values (if applicable) for the column 'subcat'.

My real 'data' dataframe is 400.000 rows and the categories table is now around 100 rows but will be expanded in the future. I got this working with a for-loop, but to me this seems quite inefficient. My goal is to make the code more efficient.

See the example provided below.

```
# Create example data
data <- data.frame('text' = rep(c('blabla FOO blabla', 'blabla test','bla BAR blablabla', 'test BOO blabla'),2),
                   'category' = c('X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Z'),
                   'subcat' = rep(NA, 8))

categories <- data.frame('search_pat' = c('FOO', 'BAR', 'BOO', 'BOO'),
                         'category' = c('X', 'Z', 'X', 'Z'),
                         'subcat' = c('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4'))

# Function for assigning the subcategory to the data
assign_subcat <- function(df, searchterm, category, subcat){
  bool_mask <- (grepl(searchterm, df$text) & (df$category == category))
  df$subcat[bool_mask] <- subcat
}

# Loop over the categories dataframe to assign subcategory on the data
apply(categories, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) assign_subcat(df = data,
                                                              x['search_pat'],
                                                              x['category'],
                                                              x['subcat']))

# Desired result
       text           category subcat
1 blabla FOO blabla        X     cat1
2       blabla test        Y     NA
3 bla BAR blablabla        Z     cat2
4   test BOO blabla        X     cat3
5 blabla FOO blabla        X     cat1
6       blabla test        X     NA
7 bla BAR blablabla        X     NA
8   test BOO blabla        Z     cat4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exploit a left join operation to achieve your expected result. With the `dplyr` package you can first create a column `search_pat` that stores the keys you are looking for (in your example `"FOO"` and `"BAR"` are extracted thanks to the `str_extract` function from package `stringr`), then you join by `search_pat` and `category` and then you discard the unnecessary columns.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(search_pat = stringr::str_extract(text, paste(categories$search_pat, collapse = "|"))) %>% 
  left_join(categories, by = c("search_pat", "category"), suffix = c("_to_be_removed", "")) %>% 
  select(-search_pat, -subcat_to_be_removed)

#                text category subcat
# 1 blabla FOO blabla        X   cat1
# 2       blabla test        Y   <NA>
# 3 bla BAR blablabla        Z   cat2
# 4 blabla FOO blabla        X   cat1
# 5       blabla test        Z   <NA>
# 6 bla BAR blablabla        X   <NA>
```

Comment: Does this work for the regular_expression search I do with grepl() function?

Comment: With the `grepl()` function you are basically saying that, for each row, the `search_pat` variable in `categories` should be *included* in `text`, right? The left join supposes that they are equal, but it does not account for only inclusion.. Do you have cases in which you need to match, say, `cat1` with `example_cat1`?

Comment: Yes it should be included in the text. The text is handwritten by a person and is a character field which contains around 100 words, but is dynamic in length. I want to check if the word provided in 'search_pat' is in the field 'text' if it is and the 'category' is also matched, the subcat must be assigned.

Comment: @daan-93 I've updated my solution after your additional explanation, check it out and tell me if it's what you were looking for

Comment: Hi Ric S, thanks for your responses so far. Very helpful, but still not entirely the full solution. With your solutions I come to realize that I could have better formulated my question. There are duplicate search_pat values for some categories, so with your solution, these are all matched with the first hit on the str_extract. So this is not entirely the right solution yet. But I'm getting there :) Again, thank you so far, do you have an idea how to resolve this 'last' issue?

Comment: In order to make your last issue clear, could you add to your sample dataframe an example of such situation, along with its expected output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217781/discussion-between-daan-93-and-ric-s).